How to include completions for one command in those of another
I have a command ts which takes as its arguments a command and that command's arguments. I want tab-completion to "do the right thing", namely:
When I type, for example ts foo<tab> bash should try to auto-complete and find any command beginning with foo. I've got this working thus:
complete -F __ts_bash_completions ts

__ts_bash_completions () {
    COMPREPLY=();

    # if there's only one word on the command line
    if [ "$COMP_CWORD" -eq 1 ]; then
        COMPREPLY=($(compgen -c -- "${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"));

Once it has a complete command name, I want tab-completions for subsequent arguments to use the tab-completion semantics of that first argument. If there is no completion function defined for that first argument I have that working just fine too. Carrying on from the above, this works:
    # otherwise ...
    else
        local command_completion_function="$(complete -p ${COMP_WORDS[1]} 2>/dev/null|sed 's/.*-F \([^ ]*\) .*/\1/')"

        if [ -z "$command_completion_function" ]; then
            COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "$(ls)" -- "${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"));

But where I'm struggling is with the last requirement, that if there is a completion function available it should be used, and I just can't get that damned thing to work. I've seen this question and its answer and tried to generalise it thus. Again, carrying on from the above:
        else
            echo using $command_completion_function
            echo COMP_CWORD="$COMP_CWORD"
            echo COMP_LINE="$COMP_LINE"
            echo COMP_WORDS="${COMP_WORDS[*]}"

            COMP_CWORD=$(( $COMP_CWORD - 1 ))
            COMP_LINE=$(echo $COMP_LINE|sed "s/^${COMP_WORDS[0]} //")
            unset COMP_WORDS[0]
            echo COMP_CWORD="$COMP_CWORD"
            echo COMP_LINE="$COMP_LINE"
            echo COMP_WORDS="${COMP_WORDS[*]}"

            $command_completion_function
        fi
    fi
}

Everything looks OK to me as far as I can tell from the echo of the various COMP_* variables, but can anyone spot the silly mistake?

FYI, I'm not sure that SO is the right place to ask, you might have better luck at superuser.com, see e.g. this: https://superuser.com/search?q=%5Bbash%5D+completion

It's on-topic here.

Shellcheck identifies several problems with the code.  The report that it produces includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run Shellcheck on all new and modified shell code.

unset COMP_WORDS[0] (even if it doesn't malfunction as described in Bash Pitfalls #57 (unset unquoted array element)) will leave COMP_WORDS as a sparse array.  Index zero will be undefined, but other indices will be unchanged.  One way to remove the first element without making a sparse array is: COMP_WORDS=( "${COMP_WORDS[@]:1}" )

Thank you @pjh for the note about unset, I wondered if that change would fix it but alas not. All the things shellcheck warns about do not seem to be relevant. SC2207 just wants me to split a string on spaces using a different method; SC2155 is unaware that I am in fact dealing with errors; SC2086 is irrelevant because function names can't have spaces in and command names with spaces in are silly and I don't have any; SC2001 is purely a matter of preferred style.

I've figured it out. The error was that if there was a completion function already defined for a command I would call that, but I wasn't dealing with the case where that returns nothing. My test case was ls, which on my machine has ...
$ complete -p ls
complete -o bashdefault -o default -F _fzf_path_completion ls

Note the -o bashdefault -o default, which kick in if the function doesn't set a COMPREPLY. -o bashdefault says "if we've got nothing, apply the bash defaults". -o default says "if we've still got nothing, apply the readline defaults".
So the fix is to say this at the top of the file:
complete -o bashdefault -o default -F __ts_bash_completions ts

There's probably a way of applying those only if the command passed as the first argument has them defined for its completions, but just applying them globally is good enough for my use cases.
The complete fixed script reads:
complete -o bashdefault -o default -F __ts_bash_completions ts

__ts_bash_completions () {
    COMPREPLY=();

    if [ "$COMP_CWORD" -eq 1 ]; then
        COMPREPLY=($(compgen -c -- "${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"));
    else
        local command_completion_function="$(complete -p ${COMP_WORDS[1]} 2>/dev/null|sed 's/.*-F \([^ ]*\) .*/\1/')"

        if [ ! -z "$command_completion_function" ]; then
            COMP_CWORD=$(( COMP_CWORD - 1 ))
            COMP_LINE=$(echo $COMP_LINE|sed "s/^${COMP_WORDS[0]} //")
            COMP_WORDS=( "${COMP_WORDS[@]:1}" )

            $command_completion_function "${COMP_WORDS[0]}" "$2" "$3"
        fi
    fi
}


The else part be like this:
    else
        local myname=$1
        local padding=$( printf '%*s' ${#myname} ' ' )
        local realcmd=${COMP_WORDS[1]}

        # Change
        #
        #   ts realcmd arg1 arg2 ...
        #
        # to
        #
        #   realcmd    arg1 arg2 ...
        #
        COMP_LINE=$( printf '%s\n' "$COMP_LINE" \
                     | sed -E -e "s/^$myname( +)$realcmd/$realcmd\1$padding/" )
        COMP_WORDS=( "${COMP_WORDS[@]:1}" )
        (( --COMP_CWORD ))

        $command_completion_function "$realcmd" "$2" "$3"
    fi


Thanks for pointing out that $command_completion_function needs to have args passed to it - although it seems that most completions ignore them and just look at the COMP_* variables, so that wasn't the issue - or at least not all of it.
